# Pulling table data using "simple html parser"

Tags: php

Hey guys been trying to grab table information from a site. I was following other responses to similar questions but cant seem to get it to work for the site in question.  I'm trying to pull the data for "Ex-Date    Record Date Pay Date    Declared Date   Type    Amount" here is the code I am currently trying to make work, thx for your help!

```
<?php
require_once('libs/simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('https://ycharts.com/companies/WFC/dividend');

$table = $html->find('div[id=dataTableBox] table', 1);
$data = array();

foreach($table->find('tr') as $row) {
  $rowData = array();
  foreach($row->find('td') as $cell) {
   // push the cell's text to the array
   $rowData[] = $cell->innertext;
  }
  $data[] = $rowData;

}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the table with class "histDividendDataTable" below, so try:

```
$table = $html->find('table.histDividendDataTable',0);
```